# How to send quickly NMEA sentences from UDP client via Python?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I am using Python version 2.7. I would like to send data via UDP client. However, when i go to the line my the sending of sata is too slow.

Could you help me to accelerate my program? I am a beginner in network using Python.

Thank you in advance

Here is my script.

```
import socket
import time


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5001
BUFFER_SIZE = 512
MESSAGE = " $POS,Target,1418345.36,4188240.67,14.16,350\r"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
while 1:
    print "send"
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
    #time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "too slow". How did you measure it? Did you compare it with other programs on the same platform which are faster (otherwise it might just be what your platform can handle)? Why do you use UDP at all (no detection of packet loss and reordering)? Apart from that: the smaller your messages the slower it gets since there is some significant overhead per message. Thus, merging multiple messages into one sent can help to speed up the transfer.

Comment: Please provide the definition of "slowness" and how "fast" you expect the code to be.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are the slowest part of your loop is `print` statement. It is usual for some IDEs and consoles.

```
while 1:
    print "send"
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
```

Remove `print "send"` and see if it helps.